# sencha touch 2 - Store - [WARN][Ext.dataview.NestedList#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on small json example and I'm getting the error

```
[WARN][Ext.dataview.NestedList#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found "
```

when i try to access store from nested list

**> here is the code for Store**

```
    Ext.define('kids.store.vids',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype: 'vids',
    config: {
        type: 'tree',
        fields: ['id' , 'title' ],
        root: { leaf: false },
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'resources/jsonfile/jsonfile.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items.feed.Lang.Type'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

**

> **View**

```
Ext.define('kids.view.VidList',{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'vidlist',
    fullscreen: true,
    requires: [
        'Ext.NestedList',
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'kids.store.vids',
        'Ext.data.TreeStore',
        'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    ],
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'nestedlist',
                title: 'video list from model vids',
                displayField: 'title',
                layout: 'vbox',
                store: 'vids',
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Am i doing anything wrong here?

I've added stores, views in app.js

Comment: This could be of some help to you: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?186957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring your store, use storeId instead of xtype to identify the store:

```
Ext.define('kids.store.vids',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        storeId: 'vids', // use this as the value of the 'store' property in your list
        type: 'tree',
        fields: ['id' , 'title' ],
        root: { leaf: false },
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'resources/jsonfile/jsonfile.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items.feed.Lang.Type'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

Comment: skydump: thanks for your reply, i changed it to storeId, but still issue is the same.

Comment: skydump: Ignore my earlier message, it worked :) thanks, but we need put storeId inside the config. but now i ran into another issue..."Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isLeaf' " ... any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have leaf: true on the leaf items in your json file?

Comment: yes, example is here `                      "id": 13,
                        "title": "third rhyme",
                        "img_tmb": "resources/images/products/jean.jpg",
                        "vid_url": "http://youtube.com?v=rhyme3",
                        "leaf": true`